# SQL Error: Returned value is boolean?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I did already used `mysqli`, the `$database->query(...);` and the `fetch_assoc()` function but this time, I am very confused...

My PHP is always telling me:

> PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on null in /var/www/vhosts/httpdocs/afterUpdate.php:24

This is my code:

```
if($database->connect_errno){
$myfile = fopen("httpdocs/wp_all_import.txt", "w");
fwrite($myfile, "+++ After Update +++\n+++Couldn't connect to database!+++\n\n");
fclose($myfile);
}

$values = $database->query("SELECT `ID` FROM `fWR6qIN_posts` where post_type = product AND post_status = publish");

$k = 0;
$count_values = mysqli_num_rows($values);
$myfile = fopen("httpdocs/wp_all_import.txt", "w");
fwrite($myfile, $count_values . "\n");
fclose($myfile);

while($row = $values->fetch_assoc()){
    if($row["ID"] != null){
        $k = $k + 1;
    }
}
```

But where the hell is the error? - My other PHP file looks exactly the same it is working?

I get at `mysqli_num_rows` and at `fetch_assoc()` this error. But normally I should get returned 2039 IDs??

I do not get a database error! - Connection is established!

Greetings and Thank You!

Comment: Obviously you forgot quotes.

Comment: @Jan Update the question, dont put code in comments. Also backticks and quotes are different. Quotes are for strings. Backticks are for columns/tables/dbs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could be you missed  quotes

```
  $values = $database->query("SELECT `ID` 
            FROM `fWR6qIN_posts` where post_type = 'product' AND post_status = 'publish'");
```

Comment: Thank. I thought only vars must be quoted...

Comment: You must quote also literal values  othewise the sql engine use these values  as column name  ..